# Writing array values to a worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I was able to write the values in array x(n,3) if I enter the UDF shown below as array formula.  (The UDF below is only used for demonstration purpose. The actual task involves frequent changes of the array dimension as determined by the number n.)   Instead of entering the UDF as an array formula by highlighting the range (in excess of 150 rows) every time, I try to automate the process by using the function "Resize".   I get "#Value!" error in Cell "K1".  It also gives me "#Value!" if I enter the UDF as an array formula.

Please advise.

```
Function Loadnumbers(n%, alpha#)
Dim Destination As Range
Set Destination = Range("K1")
Dim I As Integer
ReDim x(n, 3) As Double
        For I = 1 To n
                For J = 1 To 3
                    x(I, J) = (x(I, 1) + 1) * alpha
                    x(I, J) = (x(I, 1) + 2) * alpha
                    x(I, J) = (x(I, 2) + 2) * alpha
                Next J
        Next I
Destination.Resize(UBound(x, 1), UBound(x, 3)).Value = x() 
'The above statement gives me "#Value!" error either in a single cell ("K1") or the array.
'Loadnumbers = x() 
'The above statement works using this statement as I enter as an array formula
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change with a function the content of other cells:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/170787

If you want to change another cell then you'll have to use a sub. If you couple the sub with an event (for example Worksheet_Change or Worksheet_SelectionChange) then you can get a similar result. But to avoid slowing down you Excel too much, I'd recommend that only the change or a few cells on the sheet can trigger such an event. Example:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Intersect(Target, Range("A1:C4")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Application.EnableEvents = False

'Do you things

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```